# How do I make global event in unity3?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making tour-based game in unity.
I would like to have in (almost)all my classes a function `OnNextRound`,
 which will be called when user clicks 'next round' button.

```
void OnGUI() {
    // ...

    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10f, Screen.height - 40, 100, 30), "next round")) {
        // here call all OnNextRound functions
    }
}
```

Some of classes that also have to contain this `OnNextRound` function aren't extending `MonoBehaviour`:

```
public class SomeClass {
    // some vars and functions here
}
```

And instantiaded by this way:

```
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass(/* some params */);
```

These classes also have to contain `OnNextRound` function.

So, I want to call all functions named `OnNextRound` in every instance of every class.

How to make this, or maybe it's impossible to do it this way? If it's impossible, so how can I reach similar effect?

I am new to C#, however I have experience in other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a simple `event`.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class EventExample : MonoBehaviour {

    public static event Action myEvent;

    void OnGUI() {
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10f, Screen.height - 40, 100, 30), "next round")) {
            myEvent();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in all scripts where you want to call your `OnNextRound()` method, add these lines:

```cs
private void Awake() {
    EventExample.myEvent += OnNextRound;
}

private void OnNextRound() {
    //Do your stuff
}
```

Anyway, a couple of words:

- Don't use `OnGUI`, use an UI Button
- The signature of the `event` must match the signature of the `OnNextRound` method. If for example your method requires a `string` parameter, then the event should be declared as an `Action<string>`. If your method has a return type, then you should use `Func` instead of `Action` (you can read in depth about `Action` and `Func` delegates on the Microsoft C# knowledge base site).

Edit: Since you added the bit about a non `MonoBehaviour` class, you can register your method to the `EventExample.myEvent` in the constructor of the class, i.e.:

```cs
public class SomeClass {

    public SomeClass () {
        EventExample.myEvent += OnNextRound;
    }

    private void OnNextRound() {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. Your edit wasn't required, I knew that I can make It in constructor. I said I have some experience ;) However thank you for time spent on answering this question.

Comment: And why shouldn't I use `OnGUI()`?

Comment: `OnGUI` is more than 3 years old, it was meant to be used for UI before Unity 4.6, and it's slower than the new UI system with events etc. It's meant to be used only when customizing the editor, not for runtime anymore. You can read [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/is-ongui-laggy-obsolete.476732/) about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make a class called onNextRound then inside it delete the star() and update functions and create onNextRound () and then write your functions. MAKE IT PUBLIC

now attach this script to your main camera.

finally you can create and instance of this class inside any class you need and call that function